# Kotlin: How to map into two lists

Tags: kotlin

From a map, we could use `map` to break into list easily using

```
mapNumber.map{ it.key }
```

However, if I want both list, and want to avoid doing the `map` twice

```
val numbersInt = mapNumbers.map{ it.key }
val numbersStr = mapNumbers.map{ it.value }
```

So I could write something below

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val mapNumbers = mapOf(Pair(1, "one"), Pair(2, "two"), Pair(3, "three"))

    val numbersInt = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val numbersStr = mutableListOf<String>()

    for ((key, value) in mapNumbers) {
        numbersInt.add(key)
        numbersStr.add(value)
    }

    print(numbersInt)
    print(numbersStr)   
}
```

But that's not nice, as I have to use `mutableListOf`. I wonder if there's any collection function that could help us achieve that?

Comment: `val (keys, values) = mapNumbers.toList().unzip()`. BTW, why not just use `mapNumbers.keys` and `mapNumbers.values`?

Comment: Putting into list would have better naming and more understandable. Thanks!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd suggest to use `unzip()` standard library function.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val mapNumbers = mapOf(Pair(1, "one"), Pair(2, "two"), Pair(3, "three"))

    val (numbersInt, numbersStr) = mapNumbers.toList().unzip()

    print(numbersInt)
    print(numbersStr)
}
```

Here I've converted the `map` into a list of `Pair` objects. And then called the `unzip()` method. Using **Destructuring Declaration**, I've assigned the values returned from the `unzip()` to these variables.
See: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/unzip.html.
Hope you'll like this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you discounted dyukha's comment,  you can save the returned collections in any named variable you like.  Sure it's two lines of code, but I would think it's still very efficient and expresses exactly what you want.

```
   fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val mapNumbers = mapOf(Pair(1, "one"), Pair(2, "two"), Pair(3, "three"))

        val numbersInt = mapNumbers.keys
        val numbersStr = mapNumbers.values

        print(numbersInt)
        print(numbersStr)   
    }
```

Comment: Dyukha's comment is good and the perfect answer (as it gave both option). I'm just commenting to his inquiry why not use the `keys` and `values` directly.